# Linq select returns null for one of two nested objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Linq select statement that is supposed to return objects that have 2 nested objects. The problem is, one of the nested objects is returning null while the other is working as intended.

Here is the object being queried:

```
public class CharInvCard
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Character Character { get; set; }
    public Card Card { get; set; }
    public bool inDeck { get; set; }
    public bool inHand { get; set; }
    public bool inDiscard { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Linq query:

```
IQueryable<CharInvCard> CardsInHand = from x in db.CharInvCards
                               where x.Character.ID == character.ID && x.inHand == true
                               select x;
```

After getting the results of this query I do a foreach loop that starts like this:

```
foreach (CharInvCard deckCardRec in CardsInHand)
```

While debugging, if I inspect the contents of deckCardRec I see that it has all its properties for ID, inHand, inDeck, inDiscard and even a nested Character object (and its properties) but Card is always null.

I've checked and double checked that the Card_Id column in my database is populated with the proper ID corresponding to the Card table.

**What is causing the Card nested object is returned as null while the Character nested object to be returned properly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are referencing `Character` in your linq query, so it is included.  You are not referencing `Card` though.  Try eager loading `Cards` as below:

```
IQueryable<CharInvCard> CardsInHand = from x in db.CharInvCards.Include("Cards")
                               where x.Character.ID == character.ID && x.inHand == true
                               select x;
```

I have assumed your navigational property is named "Cards" above.